# GCM server side PHP - Unauthorized 401 Error

Tags: android, push-notification, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

I setup google developer console enabling *Google Cloud Messaging for Android*.

In the credential side I create the browser API key typing 0.0.0.0 in the refers. Actually I create both the types of key because I found different indication in different tutorial.

[browser-key picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjjFt.jpg)

[server-key picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp3ZI.jpg)

I tested the key with this PHP script

```
<?
/**
 * The following function will send a GCM notification using curl.
 * 
 * @param $apiKey       [string] The Browser API key string for your GCM account
 * @param $registrationIdsArray [array]  An array of registration ids to send this notification to
 * @param $messageData      [array]  An named array of data to send as the notification payload
 */
function sendNotification( $apiKey, $registrationIdsArray, $messageData )
{   
    $headers = array("Content-Type:" . "application/json", "Authorization:" . "key=" . $apiKey);
    $data = array(
        'data' => $messageData,
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIdsArray
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers ); 
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) );

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
?>
<?
// Message to send
$message      = "the test message";
$tickerText   = "ticker text message";
$contentTitle = "content title";
$contentText  = "content body";

$registrationId = '372CBFD0C4BFE728';
$apiKey = "AIzaSyDeNN1XJBFGE_lJ_35VMUmx5cUbRCUGkjo";

$response = sendNotification( 
                $apiKey, 
                array($registrationId), 
                array('message' => $message, 'tickerText' => $tickerText, 'contentTitle' => $contentTitle, "contentText" => $contentText) );

echo $response;    
?>
```

I expect to obtain something like that

```
{"multicast_id":6782339717028231855,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

But I obtain (with both keys) *Unauthorized 401 Error*.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: thanks for pointing me this: curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 ); without this I got Unauthorized 401 Error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of entering `0.0.0.0` as allowed referrers or allowed IPs, don't enter anything. That should work.

Comment: I am also getting the same error. How you solved this, i am doing testing in localhost and getting unauthorized-401-error. Can you please help here

Answer (score 0):

Don't enter anything in the IP address field.It works like a charm.
Also make sure you are using the Server key in server side and proper sender id android client.